# I want to understand the exact reason why overflow:hidden and display:inline-block is used here

Tags: html, css

friends, sorry for that irritating questions but I didnt really get the sense of some stuff here, im new to HTML/CSS...

**overflow:hidden under ul{}**
if I dont use it here, then the green background of the ul element doesnt appear anymore. and it is used to cut content which is bigger than its element. but in that code, which content is bigger than which element so that the background disappears? in other words why does the background of the total width of that ul-element dissappear because of these floating li-elements?

**display: inline-block**
I was wondering about the sense of inline-block here. the only thing I recognized is, that by using inline-block here, the vertical padding does work now. so why doesnt vertical padding work here if i use block or inline instead of that inline-block, I thought padding does work in ALL directions no matter if block inline or inline-block?

**li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropdown-btn {**
does **li a**: hover mean that the code is for all "**a**" which are **directly** under the parent "**li**" or also for the "**a**"s within the  (which are not directly under the parent li because their parent is div)?
And what does **.dropdown:hover .dropdown-btn exactly** mean?

Heres the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="reset.css">      
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">

            <a href="#" class="dropdown-button">Dropdown</a>

            <div class="dropdown-menu">                 
                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                <a href="#">Link 4</a>
            </div>

        </li>

    </ul>

</body>
```

And the CSS file:

```
body {
font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
max-width: 960px;                      
margin: 0 auto;                        
padding: 20px;                    
}

ul {
list-style-type: none;             
margin:0;
padding: 0;
background-color: #1ebb90;
overflow: hidden;                     
}

li {
float: left;
}

li a, .dropdown-button {                  
display: inline-block;                  
color: #ffffff;
text-align: center;
padding: 18px 22px;
text-decoration: none;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get things started, I can help with the `overflow:hidden`. That is because of the css `float` instruction.

When you `float:left` or `float:right` a couple of elements, they will go side-by-side... but they will also lose their height.

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="boxLeft">Box Left</div>
    <div id="boxRight">Box Right</div>
</div>

* {position:relative;box-sizing:border-box;}
#wrap{width:70%;border:2px solid red;}
    #boxLeft {background:pink;}
    #boxRight{background:palegreen;}
    [id^=box]{width:50%;height:40px;padding:30px;text-align:center;}
```

[Demo 1 - Not floated](https://jsfiddle.net/k545ans3/)

[Demo 2 - Floated, height is gone](https://jsfiddle.net/k545ans3/1/)

[Demo 3 - Fixed height with overflow on parent](https://jsfiddle.net/k545ans3/2/)

Comment: thanks for your answer ;) that solved my overflow problem

Answer (score 0):

The **li a:hover** means any `a` tag under the li -- not necessarily directly under the li.

[See this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dy4r9687/)

**.dropdown:hover .dropdown-btn**

This means: when user hovers over an element with class="dropdown", the child element with class="dropdown-btn" gets styled.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/oo4vupuL/)

Comment: thanks for your answer gibberish, that solved it for me